# Help finding a Nietzsche quote

Tags: nietzsche

I am trying to recall a F. Nietzsche quote that I like, but I cannot hit the right words on Google in order to find it.

The content of the quote (as I recall) is that in our vanity we want people to think that the stuff that we do are difficult though we find it easy (secretly).

I am sorry if this question is ill-posed and un-interesting, but I hope that some of you will point me in the right direction, else I will have to flick through all the pages. I think that it is either from Jenseits Gut und Böse or Morgenrote.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Human all-to-human pt. 2, aphorism 181 comes very close, but I recall it as being a shorter aphorism ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

143. 

Was wir am besten tun, von dem möchte unsre Eitelkeit, daß es gerade als das gelte, was uns am schwersten werde. Zum Ursprung mancher Moral.

Our vanity would have it that the things we do best are the very things
that are most difficult for us. On the origin of many morals.

Jenseits von Gut und Böse: Vorspiel einer Philosophie der Zukunft

Beyond Good and Evil: Prelude to a Philosophy of the Future

Comment: Maybe OP was incorrectly recalling the meaning of the quote for which he/she was searching, but do these two not mean two separate things? OP's understanding was that as a result of one's narcissism, one would desire that those things he finds easy to do are thought of by others as difficult. However, from my understanding of the actual quote you have written, does it not mean, instead, that as a result of one's futility (the other definition of vanity), what one does best is most difficult for him? Otherwise, if man wasn't futile, then what he did best would come easily - or easier - to him.

Comment: @AdityaTomar I presume the OP was more concerned with finding the original text than offering a view. It might be better to take up your comment as a separate question, thus, let others interested in Nietzschean thought also into discussion.